# Comparing two CSV objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to compare two CSV files to see if they are different. I was thinking I could do that with `Compare-Object`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$csvA = ConvertFrom-CSV "A,B,C`n1,1,1`n1,1,1"
$csvB = ConvertFrom-CSV "A,B,C`n1,1,1`n1,1,2"
Compare-Object $csvA $csvB
```

There is no output on the last line. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Compare-Object got me at first also...

Try it like this:

```
Compare-Object $csvA $csvB -Property A,B,C
```